# jQuery shift focus to div tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, focus

I've created Tabs on my page exactly as on this demo page. The page uses jQuery Tools. 
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/index.htm

Now I want to shift the focus on a tab based on an event through jQuery. How can I accomplish that? Not sure if `jQuery.scrollTo` is the right way to go. I'm willing to do some hacking, but need some direction to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [docs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html#api)

On demo page you can change active tab with something like this: 
`$("ul.tabs").data("tabs").click(1);`